# How to plot grouped bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I want to make multiple Bars in my graph and the color of each bar should be different. I have written the code:

```
 barWidth = 0.125

ET1 = [24,78,90]
ET2 = [45,73,52]
ET3 = [18,38,29]
ET4 = [25,18,13]
ET5 = [45,72,41]

br1 = np.arange(len(ET1))
br2 = [x + barWidth for x in br1]
br3 = [x + barWidth for x in br2]
br4 = [x + barWidth for x in br3]
br5 = [x + barWidth for x in br4]

plt.bar(br1, ET1, color= 'r', width = barWidth,
        edgecolor ='grey', label ='e+1')
plt.bar(br2, ET2, color= 'b',width = barWidth,
        edgecolor ='grey', label ='2e+1')
plt.bar(br3, ET3, color= 'y',width = barWidth,
        edgecolor ='grey', label ='3e+1')
plt.bar(br4, ET4, color= 'g',width = barWidth,
        edgecolor ='grey', label ='5e+1')
plt.bar(br3, ET5, color= 'pink',width = barWidth,
        edgecolor ='grey', label ='7e+1')

plt.xlabel('SIZE', fontweight ='bold', fontsize = 15)
plt.ylabel('TIME', fontweight ='bold', fontsize = 15)
plt.xticks([r + barWidth for r in range(len(ET1))],[11,18,44])

plt.legend()
plt.savefig('Comp1.png')
plt.show()
```

[image]

The code runs well for all the bars but the problem is I am not getting the bars for the 3rd data `input(ET3(3e+1))`, It should be of yellow color but I am not getting it in my graph.

Comment: Well, you writing ed**5**ecolor replacing the `g` with a `5` .... . You also need a smaller barwidth to fit 5 bars.  (Maybe `barWidth=0.18`?)

Comment: @JohanC Thank you I have edited the question please see .

Comment: For your last bar you need `plt.bar(br5, ET5, ...`  while you wrote br**3** there.

Comment: @JohanC Thank you so much sir.

Answer (score 0):

- The issue with the existing code was resolved by a comment, and resulted from a typo, `plt.bar(br3, ET5,...` where `br3` should be `br5`, as pointed out by [@JohanC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12046409/johanc)
- Grouped bars can be more easily created by loading the data into pandas and plotting with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), which uses `matplotlib` as the default backend.

  - This reduces the code from 22 lines, to 11 lines (not including code for annotations, since that's optional).

```py
import pandas as pd

# create the dataframe from the existing data
df = pd.DataFrame({'e+1': ET1, '2e+1': ET2, '3e+1': ET3, '5e+1': ET4, '7e+1': ET5}, index=[11, 18, 44])

# display(df)
    e+1  2e+1  3e+1  5e+1  7e+1
11   24    45    18    25    45
18   78    73    38    18    72
44   90    52    29    13    41

# plot the dataframe and format it
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', width=.75, rot=0, color=['r', 'b', 'y', 'g', 'pink'], ec='gray')
ax.legend(loc=2)
ax.set_xlabel('SIZE', fontweight ='bold', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_ylabel('TIME', fontweight ='bold', fontsize = 15)

# add annotations if desired
for c in ax.containers:
    # set the bar label
    ax.bar_label(c, padding=3, rotation=0)
    
# pad the spacing between the number and the edge of the figure
ax.margins(y=0.1)

# extract the figue object and save
ax.get_figure().savefig('Comp1.png')
```

[image]